# Using Google Apps Script code to create a custom menu in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, menu

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
          .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2'))
      .addToUi();
}
```

I got this error:Error Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.

This happens when I run the following line of code (as it is on Google Apps Script website) to create a custom menu:

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared is definitely correct, I was able to run it without issues and got the following menu out of it:

[image: Running code]

I was also able to reproduce the issue, I got the same error message when running the code from an unbound script, this means that the script got created directly from https://script.google.com/ and as such is not really tied to any one Google sheet, however in this code the function

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
```

Needs the script to be created directly from the sheets UI as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#custom_menus_dialogs_and_sidebars) which explains why the "from this context" part of the error.

There is also the possibility of the script being ran from an account that somehow does not have access to the sheet it tries to run the code on, this is far less likely but please do take a look at the logged in user when trying to run this script.

If you'd like to understand bound vs unbound scripts better you can use this documentation:

- [Bound scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)
- [Unbound scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This error arises sometimes even with bounded scripts. Somehow script losts connection with opened spreadsheet.
To renew, close apps scripts page and open it fresh from a spreadsheet menu.
Often this allows use UI smoothly even from a script page.